# make an arrow on the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made 3 columns in a row. I'm trying to get an effect that an arrow shows up as cursor hovers one of the columns or as one of them is clicked on. Is there any built-in class of html or CSS to do this? `the link to my code: https://codepen.io/BeauBo/pen/gxmpLK?editors=1111` Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should post your code within your question so that future people will be able to learn from this question.

Comment: did you already tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in class for this. Simply add the cursor you want to the id of that column.

```
#online {
  cursor: e-resize;
}
```

Try one of these: 
e-resize
s-resize
w-resize
ne-resize
nw-resize
se-resize
sw-resize

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=e-resize

I forked your CodePen: https://codepen.io/solona/pen/OjpdbE?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

I edited your pin wasn't exactly sure what you wanted but this is what I came up with.

```
.arrow-bar:hover:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 42%;
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid salmon;
    clear: both;
 }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjWqbx?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Example with a fontawesome chevron applied via pseudo code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
/*  var url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/ESL_SC2?callback=?";
  $.getJSON(url,function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
});*/
  
 /*Keep .outline in the center of window*/
function mov_outline(){
var wid_height = $(window).height();
var wid_width = $(window).width();

var outline_height = $('.outline').height();
var outline_width = $('.outline').width();
 
  $(".outline").css('top',wid_height/2-outline_height/2).css('left',wid_width/2-outline_width/2);
    }
  mov_outline();
  $(window).resize(function(){
    mov_outline();               
                   });
 
  });
/**************/
```

```css
body{
  background: pink;
  
}
.outline{
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  
  background:none;
}
.display{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: salmon;
  
  color: white;
}
#all,#online{
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}
#offline{
  
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#all:hover:after, #online:hover:after, #offline:hover:after {
  content: "\f13a";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  bottom: 0;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="outline">
    <div class="row display">
      <div class="col-xs-4 " id="all">All</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 "id="online">Online</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 "id="offline">Offline</div>
    </div>
  
  </div>  
</div>
```